# Paramiko return code127 against command that actually exist

Tags: python, linux, ssh, paramiko

During automating SSH routine using paramiko to linux pc, I am encountering an issue where for the existing command, I am not able to execute it successfully as "command not found" 127 response code is received on command execution.

I have tried all sort of ways exec_command(), crosschecking manually (the command work fine), change directory to the path of command before execution, still no luck.

However, the same command works well with Java. Any thoughts on it.

Comment: Could you provide more insights? Like tracebacks, the command, the code, etc ..

Comment: We really do need a [mcve]; with only a description and no actual code, it's next to impossible to debug. Note that a "minimal" reproducer doesn't need to give away secrets -- you can just run something silly like `ls`, so long as it demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what your real problem is but you can use full pathname to the command which is supposed to always work. Like

```
exec_command('/bin/ls')
```